# How to get NUMBER in a string "constant-string-NUMBER-*"?

Tags: php, regex, string, variables

I've strings like `constant-string-NUMBER-*` where

- `constant-string-` is a costant string (that I know and can use in the effort of getting the NUMBER) e.g. `fix-str-`
- `NUMBER` is any natural number
- `-*` can be any string

String-result examples:

```
fix-str-0
// result: 0

fix-str-0-another-str
// result: 0

fix-str-123
// result: 123

fix-str-456789
// result: 456789

fix-str-123456789-yet-another-str
// result: 1234567899

fix-str-999999-another-str-123
// result: 999999
```

I would like to extract the NUMBER from those strings in PHP so that I can associate this number to a variable e.g. `$numberFromString = ?`.

Any insight?

Comment: Can you add a sample string and the expected result ?

Comment: One possible way to do so without regex, based on your fixed string examples, would be to `explode` the string on the `-`'s. If the array returned from explode has `count(array) >= 3`, then use the value from array[2].

Comment: 5th result is a typo with extra `9`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
fix-str-(\d+)
```

- `fix-str-` match this string.
- `(\d+)` followed by one or more digits, and save the number inside the first capturing group.

**EDIT**

From @user3783243, we can also use `fix-str-\K\d+`, without the need of a capturing group.

```
fix-str-\K\d+
```

- `fix-str-` match this string, then..
- `\K` reset the starting point of the reported match.
- `\d+` then match one or more digits.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4hEPc5/1)

```php
<?php 
$str ="fix-str-123456789-yet-another-str fix-str-234";

$pattern = "/fix-str-\K\d+/";

preg_match($pattern, $str, $arr1); //Find only the first match.

echo "The first match: " . $arr1[0]; //Output: 123456789

echo "\n\n\n";

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $arr2); //Find all the matches.

echo "All the matches: " . implode(',', $arr2[0]); //Output: 123456789,234
?>
```

Comment: @user3783243 That is a perfect catch, I will update the answer with that :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your string examples, there are two possible ways. One way could use `explode`, then of course the other way could be with `preg_match` for regex. I'll show both ways, only to show that regex is not always absolutely necessary.

Using `explode`:

```
$strings = [
'fix-str-0',
'fix-str-0-another-str',
'fix-str-123',
'fix-str-456789',
'fix-str-123456789-yet-another-str',
'fix-str-999999-another-str-123',
];

$match = [];
$matches = [];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $match = explode('-', $string);
    
    if (count($match) >= 3) {
        $matches[] = $match[2]; // Array offset 2 has the number
    }
}

foreach($matches as $found) {
    echo $found, PHP_EOL;
}

// Output:

0
0
123
456789
123456789
999999
```

Using `preg_match`:

```
$strings = [
'fix-str-0',
'fix-str-0-another-str',
'fix-str-123',
'fix-str-456789',
'fix-str-123456789-yet-another-str',
'fix-str-999999-another-str-123',
];

$match = [];
$matches = [];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
      // match 1 or more digits, store to $match
    preg_match('/(\d+)/', $string, $match);
    
    if (!empty($match)) {
        $matches[] = $match[0]; // use the first match
    }
}

foreach($matches as $found) {
    echo $found, PHP_EOL;
}

// Output:

0
0
123
456789
123456789
999999
```

Answer (score -1):

You can represent a string as an array of characters. Use the PHP substr() Function, where the second argument is the number from which your string is left.

Example. Return "world" from the string:

```
<?php
echo substr("Hello world",6);
?>
```

Info from here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp

Comment: This solution would be finite. OP is looking for a dynamic solution, and to do some validation on the input.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it is better to always use a universal solution. I am a beginner, so I decided to offer the answer that I know, and which is working in this case!